# Unable to use Resource owner credentials of Oauth2 for Rdio

Tags: authentication, oauth, rdio

We are using rdio to get music from rdio in our app. We have used OAuth2.0 for authentication. Currently we are using authorization code. I am exploring to switch to Resource owner credentials documented in (http://www.rdio.com/developers/docs/web-service/oauth2/auth-password/ref-oauth2-auth-password ).    I have created the app in rdio site, obtained the client_id and client_secret. I am making POST call to https://services.rdio.com/oauth2/token and passing username= password= (HTTP Authorization header method of client verification) . The response comes as "error_code":"unauthorized_client" "error_description": "This client is not authorized to use the password grant". I have tried to substitute username and password with real username and password, but that doesn't work. Is it the validity of client_id and client_secret that is the issue?   I've followed all the steps to T. Please let me know what am i doing wrong?
Regards Vinay

Answer (score 0):

This OAuth 2.0 grant isn't available to every one, the [documentation says](http://www.rdio.com/developers/docs/web-service/oauth2/auth-password/):

> This method is limited to trusted Rdio partners. Please contact us if you feel your application needs to use this method.